# Method to solving $a^n + b^n = c$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have been wondering for a while if there is a method to solving the following form of equation $a^n + b^n =  c$ Where a,b,c are all integers. For example, $2^n + 5^n = 29$. One can quickly see that n is 2  but is there a general method?

Comment: Maybe not. For small values of $a,b,c$ human or computer calculation can do it . But for great values always there are ones for which the most extraordinary computer can not it.

Comment: There may not be a solution. For example, take $2^n+3^n=12$, or $2^n+5^n=28$. By the way, we don't quickly see for $2^n+5^n=133$ that $n$ is $2$. It is $n=3$.

Comment: Sure, those no integer solution for $2^n+5^n=28$, but there's a real solution, 1.976319485279632321968260635508570...

Comment: @PM2Ring I took it for granted that we were looking only for integer solutions.

Comment: @Gribouillis Of course, especially when the variable's name is $n$. ;) But I figured a real solution (which I found using Newton's method) may be of interest to some readers.

Answer (score 2):

There is, in general, no closed form solution to the equation $a^x + b^x =c$.

We can (from the monotonicity of the function $x\mapsto a^x + b^x$) show that a solution **exists** for every $c>0$, but (unless ofcourse if $a=0$ or $b=0$), the solution can only be calculated numerically.

That said, if you *know* an integer solution exists, then you can find it by bisection. First, try to evaluate $a^n+b^n$ for $n=1,2,4,8,16,\dots$ until you reach some value of $n$ for which $a^n+b^n>c$. Then, use bisection to narrow down your choices for $n$. By that I mean:

- Start with $n_1,n_2$ such that $a^{n_1}+b^{n_1}\leq c<a^{n_2}+b^{n_2}$.
- Set $n=\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}$, and evaluate $a^{n}+b^{n}$.
- If $a^{n}+b^{n} < c$, set $n_1$ to $n$. Otherwise, set $n_2$ to $n$.
- Repeat step $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a\ge b\ge 2$ and we are only interested in integer solutions $n$, we have
\begin{equation}
n\log a + \log(1 + (b/a)^n) = \log c
\end{equation}
but $(1 + (b/a)^n)$ is somewhere in $[1, 2]$, hence
$ n \le \log_a c\le n + \log_a 2$. This implies
\begin{equation}
\boxed{n = \lfloor \log_a c\rfloor}\quad \text{if}\quad a > 2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
n = \lfloor\log_2 (c)\rfloor - 1\quad\text{if}\quad a = b = 2
\end{equation}
It remains to say when this sole $n$ candidate actually satisfies the equation. If it does not, there is no solution.